# GitHub: Linking to an issue from a wiki page

Tags: github

On GitHub, is there a simple way to reference an issue (eg: `#1234`) from within a markdown file such that it is displayed as a hyperlink?

I don't want to write out the full form each time, as in:

```
[#1234](//github.com/user/project/issues/1234)
```

In commit messages, issue numbers are automatically hyperlinked. Can this happen in wiki documents too?

(This is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472682/github-link-from-issue-to-wiki) which is simply asking about markdown hyperlink syntax.)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

It doesn't happen in wiki documents.

You can use a relative url  but it isn't that much of a shortcut.   It also depends on where you are in the project.

For example in the Readme.md in the master branch of the project:

`[#1](../../issues/1)`

On the github wikis:

`[#1](../issues/1)`

Anywhere:

`[#1](/user/project/issues/1)`
(h/t to VertigoRay for suggesting this)

Comment: The relative URL on a wiki page must have the format ../../issues/1.

Comment: For future reference, links to issues and other wiki pages from wiki pages must be of the format stated in the answer. However, when you _preview_ a wiki page, it seems not to be the case because the preview has an extra path element to its url. I had a double parent link which worked in the preview but when I saved the change, it referred to the user's url, not the repo's. So use the single parent url, as indicated in the answer.

Comment: And if you wanna link to a set of labeled issues, this is how it goes (in this case inside of README.md, for example): `[my label](../../issues?q=label%3A"my+label")`.

Answer (score 0):

To reference **Milestones**, you can use the same logic:

```
See the milestone [#3](/../../milestones/3)
```

Warning: it doesn't work if you put the `#tab-issues` that automatically adds at the end of the URL when you go to the milestone.