# Link github wiki to trunk code

Tags: github

In an Github wiki it is possible to embed code. Is it possible to link to source code via a filename (and line number?) from within the wiki's repo?

Ideally there would also be some type of error displayed if the referenced file was later deleted.

I looked at these issues, but they do not cover it:

[Linking to other Wiki pages on GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6474045/linking-to-other-wiki-pages-on-github)

[GitHub link from Issue to Wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472682/github-link-from-issue-to-wiki)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [wiki markdown-cheatsheet](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet#links) does show a link to a source file (in a wiki page).

You can use a simple http link, which means you can reference any file, with line number directly in that url.

```
[text](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/blob/master/utils/i18n.js#L11-L12)
```

Or you can use a relative path

```
[I'm a relative reference to a repository file](../blob/master/LICENSE)
```

But in that last case, the line numbers might not work.